# undefined vs null in React state: Unicorn ESLint plugin no-nulls vs no-useless-undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I've added Sindre Sorhus' unicorn eslint plugin to my TS react project and I'm stuck with a rule breaking loop when updating state in logic: `setSomeState(undefined)` breaks the `no-useless-undefined` rule, while `setSomeState(null)` breaks the `no-nulls` rule. Now, he added some pretty decent sources on why `null` should be avoided: https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-null.md
but I'm curious on your guys' opinion, have I been possibly doing something wrong in my React code setting my states to undefined?

Edit: `setSomeState({})` is not viable because `{}` evaluates as truthy, and `setSomeState()` without any arguments is breaking the typescript compiler.

Comment: No, that wasn't me. But, to answer your comment question, the answer depends on the original structure: if a string, then `''`, if an object, then `{}`, if an array, then `[]`, etc.

Comment: Lets say it was an object, and I do know I suck at javascript, but isn't `{}` conceptually different than `undefined` or `null` ?

Comment: It is not conceptually different, it is literally different. Unlike C#, C++,  C, Java et.al., it is rare in JavaScript to use the `null` value. Setting something to `undefined` might make sense unless you're using some library (like React) that expects the state to be usable. `undefined` is not usable and indicates a condition that is most likely not what the programmer expected - hence it throws rather than gracefully doing something else. So the linter is simply advising your to avoid situations that may end up throwing.

Comment: In general - even Sindre, the plugin author, recommends using `undefined` over `null`, and that's what React developers (that I know of) use when they want to represent "a lack of" some state/value. Especially when there are many shorthand boolean evaluations i.e. `Boolean(undefined)` or `Boolean(null)` which evaluate to `false`, while `Boolean({})` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: So, to reiterate, `{}` will not evaluate to falsey like `null`, `undefined` or `""` would, so it isn't viable.
Also, calling `setSomeState()` without arguments is breaking the typescript compiler.

Comment: then don't use the linter - seems like a fairly simple solution. Alternatively, configure the linter to turn those rules off. Problem solved.